# Hide show button when last item shows

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I want show eavry more_item on click of more and hide the more when last item shows

```
    <ul class="home_projects">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li class="more_item">4</li>
      <li class="more_item">5</li>
      <li class="more_item">6</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" class="more">more</a>
```

Using Jquery

```
$(".more_item").hide();
        $(".more").click(function() {
        $(".more_item:hidden:first").slideDown("slow");
         });
  if ($('.more_item:hidden:last').is(':visible')){
   $(".more").hide();
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: hide the more button when last item shows

Comment: Can you elobrate more

Comment: See the question first, what i am asking is i want to hide more button when  the last(6) item shows

Comment: here you go , your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/DgGvX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way -

```
$(".more_item").hide();
$(".more").click(function() {
    $(".more_item:hidden:first").slideDown("slow",function(){
      if ($('.more_item:hidden').length === 0){
        $(".more").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/cjHp7/

Answer (score 0):

When the code running to `if ($('.more_item:hidden:last').is(':visible'))`,the animation may  not finish yet,so you should write the hide code in the callback of `slideDown`, it will run when the animation is finished.

Example:

```
$(".more_item").hide();
        $(".more").click(function() {
        $(".more_item:hidden:first").slideDown("slow",function(){
         $(".more").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$('.more').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.more_item:hidden').length > 0) {
    $('.more_item:hidden:first').slideDown('slow');
  } else {
    $(this).hide();   
  }
});
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J5a5x/).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should put the last `if` in onclick handle.

Second you should not check if the last is hidden, because it's visible during animation. So.

```
$(".more_item").hide();
$(".more").click(function() {
    $(".more_item:hidden:first").slideDown("slow");
    if ($('.more_item:last').is(':visible')){
        $(".more").hide();
    }
});
```